# not able to ping/connect to rhel machine on virtual box from my Ubuntu desktop

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu desktop on top of that I have my Oracle virtual box where I have centos 7 virtual machines.

I'm able to ping my Ubuntu from virtual machine but I'm not able to ping virtual machine Centos from Ubuntu.

Can any one explain as what is missing in here, also can anyone tell me as how to configure the virtual machines on my Ubuntu desktop so that they communicate / connect each other.

ping from my ubuntu:

```
ping 192.168.122.1
PING 192.168.122.1 (192.168.122.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.5 icmp_seq=687 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.5 icmp_seq=688 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem which cased by Virtual Box networking set to *NAT*.

Setting the networking to be *Internal networking* or *Host-only networking* should solve the problem.

From [Virtual box manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html):

> 6.7. Host-only networking
>
> Host-only networking is another networking mode that was added with
>   version 2.2 of VirtualBox. It can be thought of as a hybrid between
>   the bridged and internal networking modes: as with bridged networking,
>   the virtual machines can talk to each other and the host as if they
>   were connected through a physical Ethernet switch. Similarly, as with
>   internal networking however, a physical networking interface need not
>   be present, and the virtual machines cannot talk to the world outside
>   the host since they are not connected to a physical networking
>   interface.
>
> Instead, when host-only networking is used, VirtualBox creates a new
>   software interface on the host which then appears next to your
>   existing network interfaces. In other words, whereas with bridged
>   networking an existing physical interface is used to attach virtual
>   machines to, with host-only networking a new "loopback" interface is
>   created on the host. And whereas with internal networking, the traffic
>   between the virtual machines cannot be seen, the traffic on the
>   "loopback" interface on the host can be intercepted.
>
> Host-only networking is particularly useful for preconfigured virtual
>   appliances, where multiple virtual machines are shipped together and
>   designed to cooperate. For example, one virtual machine may contain a
>   web server and a second one a database, and since they are intended to
>   talk to each other, the appliance can instruct VirtualBox to set up a
>   host-only network for the two. A second (bridged) network would then
>   connect the web server to the outside world to serve data to, but the
>   outside world cannot connect to the database.
>
> To change a virtual machine's virtual network interface to "host only"
>   mode:
>
> - either go to the "Network" page in the virtual machine's settings notebook in the graphical user interface and select "Host-only
>     networking", or
> - on the command line, type `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nic<x> hostonly;` see Section 8.8, “VBoxManage modifyvm” for details.
>
> Before you can attach a VM to a host-only network you have to create
>   at least one host-only interface, either from the GUI: "File" →
>   "Preferences" → "Network" → "Host-only network" → "(+)Add host-only
>   network", or via command line with
>
> ```
> VBoxManage hostonlyif create
> ```
>
> see Section 8.37, “VBoxManage hostonlyif” for details.
>
> For host-only networking, like with internal networking, you may find
>   the DHCP server useful that is built into VirtualBox. This can be
>   enabled to then manage the IP addresses in the host-only network since
>   otherwise you would need to configure all IP addresses statically.
>
> In the VirtualBox graphical user interface, you can configure all
>   these items in the global settings via "File" → "Preferences" →
>   "Network", which lists all host-only networks which are presently in
>   use. Click on the network name and then on the "Edit" button to the
>   right, and you can modify the adapter and DHCP settings.
>
> Alternatively, you can use `VBoxManage dhcpserver` on the command
>   line; please see Section 8.38, “VBoxManage dhcpserver” for details.

**Setting up ssh server:**

- Instructions how to set ssh server on CENTOS can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-ssh/)
- Instructions how to set ssh server on Ubuntu 16.04 can be found [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/enable-ssh-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)

Comment: @krishnathoutam - if my answer helped you, please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Comment: It works now but the issue now is am able to ping now but not able to connect to the virtual machine, not able to ssh from virtual machine to ubuntu.

Comment: @krishnathoutam -  I've added a section in my answer with links with instructions  how to set-up ssh server on centos / ubuntu